# How can I simplify this Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an app that shows some questions to the user. It has to reply in input text fields and then there's a view that checks all these results (the one below).

This view perfectly works but I know I made a mess with dictionaries and lists. I thought to create those just to prepare a results variable that then I'll print on the HTML page. How can I simplify it?

```
def check(request):
    # Initialize results
    results = []

    i = 0
    for input_name, input_value in request.POST.items():

        # Remove cfsr from inputs
        if input_name.isdigit():

            # Get the question from the input name
            question = Question.objects.get(pk=input_name)

            # Get the related correct answer to that question
            answer = question.answer

            # Create results
            results.append({'question_text': question.text, 'user_answer': input_value,
                            'correct_answer': answer.text})

            # Check if user answer is correct
            if input_value == answer.text:
                results[i]['is_correct'] = True
            else:
                results[i]['is_correct'] = False

            i += 1

    context = {'results': results}
    return render(request, 'quiz/results.html', context)
```

Comment: You should try to use forms to create the quiz and check the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make these improvements for readability:

1. Create a list of the inputs that you want to access; the `if` check for the `csrf_token` field makes the code more difficult to read, and the assumption that `csrf_token` always contains letters may not be true.
2. Remove the counter variable (`i`); counters like this in `for` loops aren't pythonic, and often just complicate the code.
3. Replace the `if/else` test for the correct answer with a boolean expression; you can always to this with `if/else` blocks that simply assign `True` or `False` to a variable depending on the result of some test.
4. Build your results dictionary completely before appending to the list to avoid having to access via its index (`results[i]...`).

   ```
   from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed, HttpResponseBadRequest

   def check(request):
       if not request.method == 'POST':
           return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])

       # guaranteed by CsrfViewMiddleware to exist
       del request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken']

       results = []
       for question_id, user_answer in request.POST.items():
           try:
               question = Question.objects.get(pk=name)
           except Question.DoesNotExist:
               return HttpResponseBadRequest("Oops!")

           results.append({
                'question_text': question.text,
                'user_answer': user_answer,
                'correct_answer': question.answer.text,
                'is_correct': value == question.answer.text,
           })

       return render(request, 'quiz/results.html', {
           'results': results,
       })
   ```

Comment: @hop Yeah there's just that problem for this answer. Thank you anyway

Comment: I think your use of `request.POST.items` is also wrong in both cases.

Comment: this still has issues when it comes to fake requests, but oh well…

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
if input_value == answer.text:
    results[i]['is_correct'] = True
else:
    results[i]['is_correct'] = False
```

with

```
results[-1]['is_correct'] = input_value == answer.text
```

and get rid of the `i`

or even better you could put that in the `results.append`

```
results.append({'question_text': question.text, 
                'user_answer': input_value,
                'correct_answer': answer.text,
                'is_correct': input_value == answer.text})
```